# Xcode- how do I bind a combobox value from AppDelegate to ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to get an array from my AppDelegate to my ViewController, every time i try to connect in in Xcode, it only lets me access the ViewController values, not the AppDelegate.

in the following code, i can use two different methods, i'm showing them both.

1. i can just bind the combobox to the serialpPortManager.availablePorts array
2. i can grab the array, and stick it into another array, have the ViewController see the array from the AppDelegate, then bind the array to the combobox

I'd like to do it the first way, but can't get it to connect in Xcode.

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject{}

@property (nonatomic, strong) ORSSerialPortManager *serialPortManager;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *availPorts;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
self.serialPortManager = [ORSSerialPortManager sharedSerialPortManager];

ORSSerialPortManager *portManager = [ORSSerialPortManager sharedSerialPortManager];
availPorts = portManager.availablePorts;
```

ViewController.m

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSString * result = [appDelegate.availPorts description];
```

how can i just have the combobox use the value from the appDelegate itself, instead of having to jump through getting the value to the ViewController? How do I right-click drag in Xcode to get the array to bind in the appDelegate?